# jQuery replace divs with values from other divs

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, loops, replace

I'm having an issue with WordPress content filters and a front end editor striping out iframes when it auto saves.

As a workaround, I'm replacing the "video-container" div and iframe with the url values of the hidden custom post meta divs since WordPress automatically filters these urls and creates the iframes.

So far, it works, but every video container is replaced by the first post meta value and it must loop through all values, if any, replacing each video container.

I'm just learning js so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Example video container: (max 3)**

```
<div class="video-container">
     <iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/q7ZnNPzEBU4?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
 </div>
```

**Example hidden post meta with the urls I need: (max 3 & ID's increment by one)**

```
<input type="hidden" id="embedurl_1" class="embedurl" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7ZnNPzEBU4">
```

**The jQuery so far: (works, but only with one value from hidden meta)**

```
if( $('#barley_the_content').length ) {
     if( $('.video-container').length ) {
          $('div[class="video-container"]').each(function (i,v) {
               $( this ).replaceWith( $( ".embedurl" ).val() );
          });
     }
}
```

**Final Working Code:**

```
if($('#barley_the_content').length){
    if($('.video-container').length){
        $('div[class="video-container"]').each(function (i,v){
            if($(".embedurl:eq("+i+")").length){
                $(this).replaceWith($(".embedurl:eq("+i+")").val());
            } else {
                $(this).replaceWith('\r\n VIDEO PLACEHOLDER \n');
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

This basically checks to see if the barley wrapper (the front end editor) and "video-container" is present, and if so, it looks for the "embedurl_*" divs (custom post meta).

If there are custom post meta values, each one will replace the corresponding "video-container" div. This prevents WordPress from removing iframe tags when it auto saves.

If no "embedurl_*" divs/values are found, but the "video-container" div exist, we simply replace it with a "VIDEO PLACEHOLDER".

For anyone new to WordPress, this saves you from giving untrusted users/authors the [unfiltered_html capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html).

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `#barley_the_content`?

Comment: It's a wrapper for front end editor that allows you to edit any content within this div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the corresponding `.embedurl` by passing the `index` of loop to [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector. However you've to check whether it exists or not before accessing it's value.

```
if( $('#barley_the_content').length ) {
 if( $('.video-container').length ) {
      $('div.video-container').each(function (i,v) {
           if($(".embedurl:eq("+i+")").length)
           $( this ).replaceWith($(".embedurl:eq("+i+")").val() );
      });
 }
}
```

*side note: you can simply access elements with a specific class using the `.` operator like `$('div.video-container')` instead of  `$('div[class="video-container"]')`*

Comment: Just a suggestion mate, while this piece of code may solve the problem, it is always better to elaborate on what was fixed in the code and why. Doing so would help newbies who are facing the same problem to understand the solution rather than blindly use it.

Comment: @Harry i hope the update explains it (*and it works as well - not familiar with wordpress and what's going on here*)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of the jQuery that might work.

```
function replaceIt(){
    //if( $('#barley_the_content').length ) {
         if( $('.video-container').length ) {
              $('div.video-container').each(function (i,v) {
                   $( this ).replaceWith( $( "#embedurl_" + (i+1) ).val() );
              });
         }
   // }
}
replaceIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simple piece of code should do the trick. If no `div.video-container` is found, the code will not error out; it just will not execute. That's one of the beauties of jQuery.

```
      $('div[class="video-container"]').each(function (i,v) {
           $( this ).replaceWith( $( ".embedurl" ).eq(i).val() );
      });
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but according to [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) eq allows you to target the selector with a value. With your code, it targets the "0" index, which changes all the video container divs to the 1st value. They must loop through the embedurl_* values.

Comment: @user2243139, you're absolutely right. Thanks for the correction; it was an oversight on my part. I have updated my code.